# Analyzing algorithms that include while loops

Tags: algorithm

When analyzing algorithms, I don't usually have issues with `for loop` while I do have problems analyzing the running time of algorithms that involves `while loop`. I'll show an example to express my question.

The following one is a part of the `coin-change algorithm` (well-known algorithm for most of us) that I am studying right now:

```
counter = 0
s = 0
while(s <= n/100)
   s = s+1
   t1 = n- 100*s
   h = 0
     while(h <= t1/50)
          h = h +1
          t2 = t1 - 50*h

...
```

Can someone explain the best way of knowing the running time of such algorithms that have nested while loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The while loop is just another way of writing a for loop so assessing complexity should not be any different.

Here, the outer `while` loop runs `n` times in complexity world (proportional to n in real world) since `s` increases by 1 for each iteration and it runs until `s` reaches a value proportional to `n`.

The inner loop which I assume you are a little confused about, runs `t1` times (again in complexity world) where `t1 = n - 100s`. Now you are thinking the algorithm is O(n^2) but `t1` decreases in each iteration so the inner loop runs fewer number of times for each subsequent iteration and may be its not O(n^2).

`t1` is different for each iteration so the entire set of iterations will run for: `n - 100 + n - 200 + n - 300 + .... 0` times. Because the numbers of terms in this series is proportional to n, the summation will have a n squared term and for reporting complexity all lower order terms are ignored so you need not worry about what the rest of the numbers sum to. This algorithm is O(n^2).

The trick is to ignore constant and lower order terms at each step and it becomes easy !

Comment: Thank you very much. The actual algorithm consists of 5 nested while loops, so I guess in this case the algorithm would run in : `(n^2)^5 = O(n^10)`. Is that right ?

Comment: Yes, if the nested loops have a similar structure. And `n^10` is really poor complexity.